# How would I keep track of a float from an external class?

Tags: c++, class

Say I have some class I refer to in main that takes in a float like this:

```
class SomeClass {
     SomeClass(float a) {

     }

     int someMethodDoingSomethingWith_a() {
          // perform something on _a
     }

     float _a;
}
```

In my main class, I will be constructing this SomeClass with a float value that will be constantly changing through the course of its process.

Whenever I perform some of the methods in SomeClass, it will be using its float _a, but I want it to be the updated float (whatever it currently is in main).

What would you recommend I do, use pointers? Please suggest what I could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then define it like:

```
class SomeClass {
     SomeClass(float & a) : _a (a) {

     }
     //....

     float &  _a;
}
int main()
{
      float x;
      SomeClass inst(x);
}
```

Now, if you change `x` in `main()`, then `_a` in `SomeClass`  will be updated accordingly. But note that this automatic change will be reflected only in `inst` instance of `SomeClass`.

Comment: @Nawaz I think storing reference in main is much better way. Because if we call constructor in some other function and not in main `_a` will point to garbage after calling this function. Even in main if you declare `_a` in some scope you will have same problem after  leaving that scope.

Comment: Now how would I refer to _a? If I wanted to use the value, would it be *_a or just _a?

Comment: @Lua: just `_a`. A reference is accessed the same way you'd access the value it references.

Comment: @Ashot: That's what I was thinking. But then the OP has asked the question in a way that made me feel that this should do his job.

Comment: @Ashot: By the way, I didn't understand when you said *"storing reference in main is much better way"*. What does it mean?

Comment: @Nawaz I'm telling, that in main you must have reference to float `float x;` and in class you mast store value of `_a` and not it's reference .

Comment: @Ashot: Please post your complete solution.:-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is different code from Nawaz one. It is more safe way of doing same.

```
class SomeClass {
public:
     SomeClass(float a) {

     }

     int someMethodDoingSomethingWith_a() {
          // perform something on _a
     }

     float  get_a()
     {
            return _a;
     }
     void set_a(float f)
     {
           _a=f;
     }
private:
     float _a;// _a is not reference anymore!!!!!!
}

int main()
{
    SomeClass S(5.7);

    //Now you can get and set a's value with get_a and set a
    S.set_a(7.1);

    return 0;
}
```

To show difference from Nawaz's solution let's consider following code, assuming, that  we are storing reference in class as Nawaz do.

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> somefunction()
{
    float x =7;
    return std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>(new SomeClass(x));
}
```

This function will return pointer to function which will have reference to something, which already removed from memory.

And Here is another problem of such code:

```
SomeClass A(25); // A._a is referring to garbage.
```

Comment: You should not access member variables directly from outside the class but use a member function: `float getValueOfA() { return _a; }` which returns the value of `a` (by-value, not by-reference). So if you need the value of `a`, you call `S.getValueOfA();` and do not store a reference to `_a` in `main()`

Comment: @rve: if you have both inlined getters and setters with no additional logic... then really the mutator and accessor don't bring much to the table. It's boilerplate code with no real utility as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @Matthieu M. I think main reason for using mutator and accessors  is that, you can change class  realization and as long as your class has same interface you don't need to change your code.

Comment: @Ashot: I know, but it often sounds like over-engineering to me. Unless you are defining an interface (of course). Isn't it one of the tenant of Agile that one should not write code "just in case" it's useful some day ?